# How does maven pick a profile (if none is set)?

Tags: maven

I have two profiles specified in my settings.xml, a and b. A is defined before b.
I just did run a `mvn clean install -X`. Did maven pick a profile?

I'm not using the `<activeProfiles>` block in my setings.xml, and I didn't specify a `-P` argument. There is no `<activation>` block in my settings either. And I don't seem to have anything in my global settings file. I also searched my project's POM and parent POM for the profile name, but I got zero matches, so I assume it's not specified in there...

I've had a look at "[Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)" in the docs but that hasn't given me any clues...

I would have expected for maven to prompt me if no profile is specified but if there are some defined in the settings...

Is it just not using any?
How does it pick a profile (if none is set)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't explicitly active a profile (by using -P profileId) and if none of the profiles is triggered by it's [activation](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Activation) then none is triggered. 
For Maven it doesn't matter if profiles are activated or not.
You can confirm this with `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:active-profiles`.
Be aware that profiles are often used for the wrong reasons. Even here at SO some give bad advices.
It would help if you would say why you want to use a profile.

Comment: I work in a fairly big IT department. Each area has their own profile and mirror. I'm one of the very few souls who work on both areas, and I was getting tired of either switching the profiles out manually or forgetting to specify what settings file to use. So I thought I'd try to merge the profiles into one file. Was just curious what would happen if I specified nothing. To answer your question: one specifies a few URLs (e.g. bug tracker) in properties, and repositories, the other server settings for localhost in properties, and repos, too. the mirrors are both for `*`, so the first one wins.